# Tags 'topdown' vs 'top-down'

Tags: discussion, tags

There are two tags:

- [topdown](/questions/tagged/topdown) with 14 entries
- [top-down](/questions/tagged/top-down) with 5 entries

There's no wiki for either, yet.

Superficially, it is trivial to merge the two - I set off to do so.  Then I found that there seems to be a product, library or feature called 'Topdown' (eg this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445638/tutorial-for-topdown-3d) or this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443086/opengl-topdown-bottomup-textures)) associated with OpenGL and 3D graphics, but the majority of the questions seem to be about 'top-down' vs 'bottom-up' approaches to design.

What should be done about this confusing situation?

- Establish whether the Topdown associated with OpenGL is real or not (a quick Google search is not conclusive).
- Create Wiki entries for both.
- Designate the [top-down](/questions/tagged/top-down) tag for general use related to 'top-down' vs 'bottom-up' vs 'inside-out' design issues.
- Designate the [topdown](/questions/tagged/topdown) for the OpenGL library if it exits.
- Clean up the existing questions, retagging many of the ones in [topdown](/questions/tagged/topdown).

Did I miss anything?

Do you know about a 'Topdown' library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd prefer [top-down-design](/questions/tagged/top-down-design) and [topdown-library](/questions/tagged/topdown-library) for clarification, assuming, of course, the library exists.

Answer (score 0):

How about `topdown-opengl` & `top-down-opengl` as aliases?

The opengl extension in auto-complete should be a clue as to correct use of the tag on future posts (unless it gets purged in the low-usage cleanup)

Comment: topdown-opengl makes sense; did you mean 'top-down-design' for the other?

Comment: Nope, I was thinking that if _top-down_ and _topdown_ are already in use, it makes sense to cater for both spellings as aliases.